# Java creating a generic class that implement another generic interface with constraints

Tags: java, generics, javacompiler

Interface to be implemented:

```
public interface Message {
}

public interface Handles<T extends Message>  {
    void hanlde(T message);
}
```

Concrete implementation:

```
public class EnforcementHandler<T extends Handles<T extends Message>> {

}
```

***Unexpected bound***

Is this pattern possible in Java?

Comment: `public class EnforcementHandler<T extends Handles<T> & Message> {` if you want `T` to implement `Message` and `Handles<T>`.

Comment: Hi @Turing85. No offense. What you're proposing won't work. The OP's _`Handles`_ is declared with a type parameter that has only one bound: _`Message`_. You're declaring _`EnforcementHandler`_ with a type parameter _`T`_ that has two bounds: _`Handles`_ & _`Message`_.  It would be impossible to actually instantiate an instance of _`EnforcementHandler`_ with a type argument of some type that both implements _`Handles`_  and also implements _`Message`_ — *as you've defined with* _`T extends Handles<T> & Message`_. [*See for yourself with an experiment I did*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_306203).

Comment: @deduper in the comment I provided, the concrete implementation of `T` (i.e. `HandlesMessage` in your code) must implement both `Handle<T>` **and** `Message`. Although this approach is highly questionable since those two implementations should be separated in two classes (since it basically says that `HandlesMessage` handles itself...), it is what I inferred OP wanted. I do not recommend using this approach, but [it would work in theory](https://ideone.com/lHtfwt). Since I do not recomment the approauch and @Louis's answer was already there (and cleaner), I just posted it as comment.

Comment: @deduper thank you for your answer. I'm building a basic composite pattern using functions that follow a custom interface. In this case the custom interface could be a Consumer<T> but the answer Louis provided was what I was looking to do.

Comment: „*...it basically says that HandlesMessage handles itself..it is what I inferred OP wanted...*“ — Would you mind if I *ask you for the specific use case* you envisaged when you were inferring such an arrangement, @Turing85? That would be very educational. TIA.

Comment: @deduper As I said: I would not recommend this approach and would strongly suggest [Louis's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63309455/4216641).

Comment: Thanks @YusbelGarcia for providing such a good problem for my daily coding kata.

Comment: public static <M extends Message, T extends Handles<M>> void enforcement(M message, Handles<M> handler){
        //Todo: Apply security
        handler.hanlde(message);
    }

Comment: you can use it to compose operations, like in OOP pipe and filters

Comment: „*...I would not recommend this approach...*“ — Hmmm. By posting the approach in your comment @Turing85, you *did* actually recommend that approach. So I'm hoping to learn something that *I* don't know, but that you *do* know. Namely: *The specific use case you envisaged when you commented?*

Comment: @deduper It is syntactically possible, bot semantically questionable. If you want to continue the discussion (although I am afraid I have no further information to provide) then invite me to a chat. Comments are not for extended discussions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must write it as `EnforcementHandler<M extends Message, T extends Handles<M>>`.

Answer (score 0):

What the exact responsibility of your *`EnforcementHandler`* is, is ambiguous.

Going by the „*Handler*“ part of its name, suggests to me that its responsibility is to „*handle*“ things. So this seems an appropriate implementation to *my* understanding…

```
public class EnforcementHandler<M extends Message> implements Handler<M>{ 
    
    public void handle( M msg ) { out.printf( "%1$70s%n ", msg.read( ) ); }
}
```

[*This demo shows how it could be used*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/ay)…

```
  ...
  Message msg = ( ) -> "Friends of space, how are you all? Have you eaten yet? Come visit us if you have time.";
  
  EnforcementHandler< Message > handler = new EnforcementHandler< >( );
  
  handler.handle( msg );
  ...
```

…Printing this friendly message to *`stdout`*…

```
Friends of space, how are you all? Have you eaten yet? Come visit us if you have time.
```